# How to convert text String to GSM 7-bit

Tags: vb.net

I have a Huawei USB Modem in IRA Mode, which only supports sending and receiving strings in the GSM 7-bit format.  I want to send AT commands to it with GSM 7-bit
text.  Is there a function to Encrypt and decrypt GSM 7 bit text?  I could not find any solution in VB.NET.  All the examples I found were in C or Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the various string encodings are handled, in .NET, via the classes derived from `System.Text.Encoding`.  The .NET Framework comes with implementations for a good number of the most common string encodings.  Unfortunately, there is apparently no built-in `System.Text.Encoding` class for the GSM 7-bit encoding (as defined by GSM 03.38).  There is an open source project, called [.NET-GSM-Encoding](https://github.com/mediaburst/.NET-GSM-Encoding), which adds support for that encoding.  That library is also conveniently available via NuGet as [Mediaburst.Text.GSMEncoding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mediaburst.Text.GSMEncoding/).